# Rails Category has many Categories?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am building a rails app for my fiance to do some very basic inventory tracking.  We have gone through several options and since I want to learn rails anyway we figured why not.  Anyway with the products structured the way they are it would be helpful if I could have some Products categorized like this.

```
    A = Parent Category
    B = Child Category
    C = Product Category
```

So thus.

```
    A->Product
    A->B->Product
    A->B->Product->C
```

Is this even remotely possible?

Answer (score 4):

These are called self-joins, and they're supported by Active Record:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#self-joins

In your example, a category might look like this:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :subcategories, :class_name => "Category",
    :foreign_key => "parent_category_id"
  belongs_to :parent_category, :class_name => "Category"
end
```

Answer (score 3):

I recently used the [Ancestry gem](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry) and it worked perfectly for what I needed. The site I used it on had a very similar request as yours and I think you could find it useful.

The only downfall to using a gem is you won't learn the internals of the Rails framework as well. But, the bonus is you get a ton of code written for you.

Here's a [RailsCasts episode](http://railscasts.com/episodes/262-trees-with-ancestry) that shows how to use Ancestry.